# generating string of set length

Tags: string, rust

I'm trying to generate a string such that if there's a list like [16,24..] and another list ["00","7F"..]

the generated list is
[00000000000000000000000000000000,7F7F7F7F7F7F7F7F7F7F7F7F7F7F7F7F, ...

in python the code would be:

```
    for l in range(16, 32 + 1, 8):
        for b in ['00', '7f', '80', 'ff']:
          do_something(b * l);
```

I'm uncertain how to accomplish this in rust, thus far I've got:

```
for &i in [16u,24u,32u].iter() {
    for n in ["00","7f","80","ff"].iter() {

    }
}
```

but i have no idea how to create the strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`repeat`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.repeat) wich was in it's own trait (`std::str::StrAllocating`), but nowadays is directly implemented on `str` directly:

```
fn main() {
    for &i in [16u, 24u, 32u].iter() {
        for n in ["00", "7f", "80", "ff"].iter() {
            println!("{}", n.repeat(i))
        }
    }
}
```

prints

```
00000000000000000000000000000000
7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f
80808080808080808080808080808080
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f
808080808080808080808080808080808080808080808080
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f
8080808080808080808080808080808080808080808080808080808080808080
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
```

[Demo](http://play.rust-lang.org/?code=fn%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20for%20%26i%20in%20%5B16u%2C%2024u%2C%2032u%5D.iter%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20n%20in%20%5B%2200%22%2C%20%227f%22%2C%20%2280%22%2C%20%22ff%22%5D.iter%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!%28%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20n.repeat%28i%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D)